# AngularJS directive: Singleton view approach?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to implement a directive for custom input validation.

Such directive is expected to be used multiple times on a page, but provide a single visual element that contains a summary for all current issues, a visual singleton.

What is the best approach to implementing such a directive - for all instances to pump details into one that does visualization?

Comment: If all the inputs/custom validator instances are on the same angular form, then a single directive on the form can access all the $error properties of any input on the form, whether they are generated by a custom validator or a standard validator using `formName.inputName.$error`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you still need a service to centralize the errors, as Robert Kuritnik explained below, so the whole thing requires: directive for validation and reporting + service for accumulating errors + directive for visualizing the data in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to create an `ValidationErrorsService` that all your custom validators would use. They'd simply add their errors to it and then have them displayed by either yet another directive or the view.

Since these errors are transient in nature service would have to provide the ability to discard previously present errors as well.

```
service.addError(errorKey, value);
service.clearError(errorkey);
```

Also make sure that your directive uses isolated scope because you'll be using several on the same page so they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: I suppose I could use a service to control a global UI element for errors summary. I just wish a service could have an HTML template associated with it, which it doesn't.

Comment: No. But a custom directive i.e. `<error-summary></error-summary>` can. Simply inject your service to this directive and display the values. Seems tedious but it's the best possible approach for your scenario. And this custom directive would be rather simple.

Comment: It will have to do. Thank you for your answers.